# Mostrar el contenido de un txt con el método readUTF

Tags: java, poo, socket, class, server

Tengo dos clases. Una servidor y otra cliente. No voy a insertar la clase servidor porque funciona correctamente. Pero en la clase cliente quiero mostrar la información que me está mandando el servidor sobre un fichero.txt con un texto en su interior. Comentado aparece una forma "cutre" de como quiero el resultado, pero lo interesante sería hacerlo en un bucle porque no se la longitud que tendría el txt.

He creado un bucle pero solo se muestra la última línea del documento.
¿Alguna sugerencia de como conseguirlo?

```
public class Cliente {

    final Integer PUERTO = 1500;

    public Cliente() {

        Socket socketCliente = null;

        DataInputStream flujoEntrada = null;
        DataOutputStream flujoSalida = null;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nombreFichero = null;

        Integer respuestaServidor = null;

        try {
            socketCliente = new Socket("localhost", PUERTO);

            System.out.println("Escribe el nombre del fichero deseado: ");
            nombreFichero = s.nextLine();

            flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(socketCliente.getOutputStream());
            flujoSalida.writeUTF(nombreFichero);

            flujoEntrada = new DataInputStream(socketCliente.getInputStream());
            respuestaServidor = flujoEntrada.readInt();

            if (respuestaServidor == 0) {
                System.out.println("El fichero no existe, lo siento macho.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Has tenido suerte.");
                System.out.println("A partir de aquí se muestra el contenido: ");
                System.out.println();

                // A partir de aquí se muestra la información enviada desde el Servidor.
                DataInputStream disFichero = new DataInputStream(socketCliente.getInputStream());

                
                while (!disFichero.readUTF().isEmpty()) {
                    String textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(textoFichero);
                }
                
                // Buscar la solución para un bucle.
                /*
                String textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
                System.out.println(textoFichero);
                textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
                System.out.println(textoFichero);
                textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
                System.out.println(textoFichero);
                textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
                System.out.println(textoFichero);
                textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
                System.out.println(textoFichero);
                textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
                System.out.println(textoFichero);
                */
                // A partir de aquí el documento ya no tiene más información y salta excepción.
                //textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
                //System.out.println(textoFichero);

                /*
                while(disFichero.readUTF() != null){
                    String textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(textoFichero);
                }
                 */
                System.out.println();
            }

            socketCliente.close();
            //flujoEntrada.close();
            flujoSalida.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cliente();
    }
}
```

No considero poner la clase Servidor porque si descomento parte del código de la clase Cliente se puede ver como muestra todo el documento por completo.

Comment: Suelo copiar texto de clases y siempre se queda fuera del cuadro de texto la sentencia de creación de clase y el último corchete, ¿por qué pasa eso? Me refiero a que 'public class Cliente { y el último corchete no sale en la caja de texto del resto de la clase si lo he metido todo en la etiqueta de code.

Comment: debes colocar 3 Backticks al principio del código y 3 al final. Pone "editar" y observa la edición que te hicieron y los vas a ver

Comment: Gracias @Yussef

Answer (score 2):

Lo correcto sería obtener la información mientras el `DataInputStream` tenga información usando [available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#available--),

> **[available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#available--)** Devuelve una estimación de la cantidad de bytes que
> se pueden leer (u omitir) de este flujo de entrada sin que la próxima
> persona que llame a un método los bloquee. La siguiente persona que
> llama puede ser el mismo hilo u otro hilo. Una sola lectura u omisión
> de esta cantidad de bytes no bloqueará, pero puede leer u omitir menos
> bytes.

de esta forma podrás obtener correctamente la información usando `readUTF()`:

```
DataInputStream disFichero = new DataInputStream(socketCliente.getInputStream());
            
     while (disFichero.available() > 0) {
         String textoFichero = disFichero.readUTF();
         System.out.println(textoFichero);
     }
```

Comment: He probado available() como me has indicado (suponiendo que dinput.available() es en realidad disFichero.available()) y la consola no me devuelve nada. Además, la clase Servidor me lanza una excepción: java.net.SocketException: Se ha anulado una conexi�n establecida por el software en su equipo host.

Comment: si, es disFichero.available()!

Comment: Pues no me funciona con ese método:(

Comment: Si antes del bucle escribo: 'System.out.println(disFichero.readUTF());' me funciona la solución que me has dado. ¿La razón? No tengo ni idea. Gracias